# Finding the value of this limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

```
lim    sin(sin(x))/x^2
x-> 0
```

The problem originally was:

```
lim     sin(sin(x))/x^k
x-> 0
```

and i had to find some integer k for which the following limit exists. I used maple to graph it and found the answer to be k = 2.

So now my question is how would i go about finding the value of the limit? Would i need to use the derivative which i figured out to be:

```
x cos(x)cos(sin(x))-2sin(sin(x))/x^3
```

But then i realized that it would still be 0 in the denominator so i am completely stumped on how to find the value of the limit.

Comment: No the limit doesn't exist, from the right it is equal to $\infty$ and from the left to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $k=-1$.  Then your limit becomes a term that goes to 0 then a term that is bounded, and  so by the squeeze theorem,  the limit is 0.

Or even simpler, take $k=0$.  In which case your limit is a continuous function (as it is for $k=-1$, now that I think about it.

Edit: Upon further reflection,  $k=1$ will work also,  by l'hopispal's rule.  An answer further down shows why no $k\ge 2$ will work, so any $k\le 1$ will work and no other

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use l'Hopital's rule to start off:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x\cos\sin x}{2x}$$

When $x\approx 0$, we have $\cos\sin x\approx \cos 0 = 1$ and $\cos x \approx 1$, and the problem becomes:

$${1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$$

However, this limit clearly doesn't exist, hence the original limit doesn't either.

Comment: what about the first problem that i solved. I said k was equal to 2. If that exponent on the x changed would it still not exist?

Comment: This logic clearly shows that for any $k\ge 2$ it won't exist, as you'd get the same numerator with a denominator that goes to 0

Comment: @Alan Well it says in the problem find the positive integer k for which the following limit exists. So that right there would be DNE. correct?

Comment: Take, generally, $k\leq 1$. So in your case, $k=1$

Comment: Well, the way you typed it it didn't say positive integer.   But if you are restricting to positive, then k=1

Comment: Yes sorry i did not include the full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ to find the value of $k$ that leads to a convergent series. Note that the function for $k=2$ does not converge.